# Как посмотреть код базовых методов и функций?

Tags: python

Хочу порыться в базовых методах Python, но получается это с переменным успехом.
Вот почему:

- Иногда я через Ctrl + нажатие открываю код метода и там всё читабельно и можно посмотреть.
- Иногда через такое же действие я открываю, но там вижу что-то подобное

```py
def __len__(self) -> int: ...
def __contains__(self, __o: object) -> bool: ...
def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[_T]: ...
def __and__(self, __value: AbstractSet[object]) -> set[_T]: ...
def __iand__(self, __value: AbstractSet[object]) -> Self: ...
```

Код отличается тем, что функции как бы "свёрнуты" а развернуть их нельзя, потому что по сути нечего разворачивать. Это не свёрнутые строки.
Файл, к слову, отличается расширением. Не `.py`, а `.pyi`

Подскажите, как достучаться до нормального кода?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Файлы с расширением `.pyi` - это так называемые файлы-заглушки, в них находятся заголовки функций, а не они сами. Логика таких функций написаны на языке программирования C и их можно найти в [репозитории исходного кода CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) на GitHub.

PS1: Встроенные функции находятся в файле [`Python/bltinmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c).

PS2: Если интересно, вот исходный код функции `len`:

```c
static PyObject *
builtin_len(PyObject *module, PyObject *obj)
{
    Py_ssize_t res;

    res = PyObject_Size(obj);
    if (res < 0) {
        assert(PyErr_Occurred());
        return NULL;
    }
    return PyLong_FromSsize_t(res);
}
```

его можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1694).

PS3: Все файлы `.pyi` находятся не в проекте [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython). а в [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed).

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Они написаны на c. Нужно пойти в репозиторий в гитхабе и там смотреть код проекта cpython.
https://github.com/python/cpython

Comment: Большое спасибо